# Error: Assigned data `0` must be compatible with existing data in R. Missing package in newly installed Linux Version?

Tags: r, dplyr

as per subject I'm getting this error in a newly installed RStudio on a newly installed Ubuntu 22. It doesn't make any difference what I type instead of 0, I always get the incompatibility error.
I have the very same program on Windows and doesn't show any error. Am I missing something?
Thank you!

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(caret)
library(DT)
data = read_csv("data.csv")
data[is.na(data)] = 0
Error:
! Assigned data `0` must be compatible with existing data.
ℹ Error occurred for column `Nation`.
✖ Can't convert <double> to <character>.
```

Comment: Without a snippet of data or a reproductible example is hard to tell. It seems like your data is "character" and you are giving it a numeric argument. Have you tried `"0"` instead of just `0`?

Comment: Yes I've tried "0". What blows my mind is that I'm running the very same program on another machine (MS) without any problem. So the data are not really important since the same file run smoothly on MS and gives an error on Ubuntu. My guess is that I haven't installed some sort of package that prevents the error.

Comment: Trick: I manually modified the csv. In the "Nation" column (see Error) there was just one blank I filled manually. That doesn't explain however why I don't get the error on the same file running on another machine.